# Reasonable price vs Reasonable pricing

Tags: word-usage

What would it be the difference between price and pricing on the statements as follows:

- Good food, reasonable pricing
- Good food, reasonable price

Looking at [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reasonable%20price%2C%20reasonable%20pricing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creasonable%20price%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creasonable%20pricing%3B%2Cc0) seems that the second is the right choice but I've come across the first quite often.

Could it be a regionalism?

Comment: An ngram of the phrase itself isn't really helpful, because you can't see the larger context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A product has a price, the amount of money charged for it.

Pricing is the policy which a company uses to decide prices.

If you are talking about an advert for a restaurant I'd say

> Good food. Reasonable prices.

Plural because there are multiple prices on a menu.

Comment: For example: "We have good food, and a *reasonable pricing* policy."